# adding a custom widget in Layout at execution

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qlayout

I'm under Ubuntu 18.04 and using last QtCreator with last Qt5 framework

I'm trying to setup a vertical layout with at top an horizontal nested layout and under a custom made widget (based on clock exemple for the moment)

I setup a fresh widget project but as I dont understand yet how to get acess to nested layout from c++ code I removed automaticaly created mainform and created layout at execution.

If I use my custom widget as window it works if I use a window and add my custom widget it works but if I add a layout, add my custom widget to this layout and call setLayout on window it disappear...

I tried almost all orders : set the layout first or after adding my widget.
I tried to call show() on my widget or not befor or after adding it to layout
I tried to add the nested layer first or last nothing change
I 've read several time exemples and manual about layout and nested one
I can see my nested layout but not my widget

here's my main :

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    QWidget w;
    w.setWindowTitle("WOUND : Windings Organiser with Usefull and Neat Drawings");

    QVBoxLayout* hl=new QVBoxLayout;// top vertical layout

    QHBoxLayout* slotqueryLayout=new QHBoxLayout; // nested first horizontal layout
    QLabel *slotqueryLabel = new QLabel("Slot number:");
    QLineEdit *slotqueryEdit = new QLineEdit("48");
    slotqueryLayout->addWidget(slotqueryLabel);
    slotqueryLayout->addWidget(slotqueryEdit);
    hl->addLayout(slotqueryLayout);

    WindingViewer* wv=new WindingViewer(&w); // my widget is just a simple canvas to draw things
    hl->addWidget(wv);
    wv->show(); // dont know if it's needed but if I remove it it dont change anything / tried to do it before or after adding to layout

    w.setLayout(hl); // if called before adding content it dont change

    w.show();
    return a.exec();
}
```

and here you can find my custom widget:

```
class WindingViewer : public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit WindingViewer(QWidget *parent = nullptr);

protected:
    void paintEvent(QPaintEvent *event) override;

signals:
public :
    int SlotNumber;
public slots:
};
```

and

```
WindingViewer::WindingViewer(QWidget *parent) : QWidget(parent)
{
    SlotNumber=3;
    resize(200, 200);
}

void WindingViewer::paintEvent(QPaintEvent *)
{

    int side = qMin(width(), height());
    QColor SlotColor(127, 127, 127);
    QPainter painter(this);
    static const QPoint slotpolygonext[4] = {
        QPoint(-2,85),
        QPoint(-3,95),
        QPoint(3, 95),
        QPoint(2, 85)
    };
    static const QPoint slotpolygonint[5] = {
        QPoint(-1,75),
        QPoint(-2,85),
        QPoint(2, 85),
        QPoint(1, 75),
        QPoint(-1,75),
    };
    painter.setRenderHint(QPainter::Antialiasing);
    painter.translate(width() / 2, height() / 2);
    painter.scale(side / 200.0, side / 200.0);
    painter.setPen(SlotColor);
    for (int i = 0; i < SlotNumber; ++i) {
        painter.drawPolyline(slotpolygonext,4);
        painter.drawPolyline(slotpolygonint,5);
        painter.rotate(360.0/SlotNumber);
    }
}
```

I hope the question is clear enough. I've search for an answer here and over internet before posting. I found few things but nothing totaly related.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The custom widget is part of the window, you could see if manually with the mouse you make the height increase.

**And then why is it hidden?**

The layouts handle size policies and use the `sizeHint()` function of the widgets to obtain the default size, and in your case the `sizeHint()` is not implemented because it is not observed when the window is displayed, the solution is to implement that method:

***.h**

```
public:
    explicit WindingViewer(QWidget *parent = nullptr);
    QSize sizeHint() const override;
```

***.cpp**

```
QSize WindingViewer::sizeHint() const
{
    return QSize(200, 200);
}
```

[image]